# Uploading image on twitter using twitpic

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mgtwitterengine, twitpic

I want to upload image on twitter.For this I used Twitpic API .I am able to upload image using  oauth in which i need to enter pin manually .Please anyone suggest me how to upload image via twitpic from mgtwitter engine so that I do not have to  enter pin manually.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out of box: [OARequestHeader](https://github.com/Gurpartap/OARequestHeader#readme)

Answer (score 1):

Tryout this:
https://github.com/domness/DWTwitPicUpload

Comment: sorry this approach does not work.First theres was some bugs in it which I remove after that also response coming is 401.