# Upload image on TwitPic using Twitter OAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter-oauth, twitpic

I know this may be the repeated question as there are many questions related to this one on SO. I have referred the below ones:

**References:**

[Uploading image on twitter using twitpic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292576/uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitpic)

[Posting image to twitter using Twitter+OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616102/posting-image-to-twitter-using-twitteroauth)

[using TwitPic + OAuth to upload a photo + tweet to Twitter (.NET C#) - why no tweet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434576/using-twitpic-oauth-to-upload-a-photo-tweet-to-twitter-net-c-why-no-tw)

It works fine as an individual. But, in that "OAuth_token" has been used and it is given statically like 3xxxxxx1-KxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxY. So in this case, it will upload an image on the same accout for which this OAuth_token is used.

I have also referred https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine.... but in this `[_accessToken key]` returns `NULL`.

I want to upload image on currently logged in account. Means, if I logged into another account next time, image must be uploaded on that account.

**Problem:**

If I give `OAuth_token` static as specified earlier, then it will upload image on that account each time though I have logged into another account.

**Question:**

Is there anyway to generate dynamic `OAuth_token` or any other way that solves this problem??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Image uploading to twitter no need to use Twipic api .Twitter API provide itself a URL for upload image 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json 
for Documentation you can follow this URL 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media**

Comment: Yes, I know that without TwitPic we can upload image. But, it is the requirement that image must be uploaded on TwitPic.

Comment: @Narayana: Do you have any code example how we can upload images using REST API 1.1? I have been trying for a couple of days, but it's not working for me. See my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518280/twitter-api-1-1-update-with-media-returns-500